# What is a graph contraction?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

The following is a homework assignment:

> Let $B$ be the set of bridges of a connected graph $G$. If $G'$ is obtained from $G$ by contracting each connected component of $G − B$ to a vertex, then $G'$ is a tree whose edges correspond to the edges in $B$.

My problem is that I'm not sure that they mean by "contracting each connected component of $G-B$ to a vertex". What do they mean by contracting?

Comment: Replace each connected component of $G-B$ by a single vertex.

Answer (score 2):

Given a subset $S\subset V$ of vertices of $G$, the **contraction** of $S$ to a vertex $v$ in $G$ is a graph $G'$ with vertex set $(V\setminus S)\cup\{v\}$ and who has all of the edges of $G$ whose ends are both in $V\setminus S$ and also an edge from $v$ to $u$ for all edges of $G$ with one end in $S$ and the other in $u\in V\setminus S$.  (Sometimes, people add a loop of $v$ for every edge with both ends in $S$, but it is clear from context that this is not the case here.)

TL:DR - you replace all of the vertices that you are contracting with a single vertex and keep all of the connections to the rest of the graph.  In your case, you are contracting many subsets at the same time, but it shouldn't be a difficulty to see how that works.

Your proof will be shorter than this post. ^_^

Comment: But if we contract each connected component to a vertex than this vertex is not connected to anything right?